# accessing html element by?

Tags: jquery

I have textarea and I want to bind function textareaCount jquery plugin, to limit input character size.

As I use it in several places in my application, I cant use on Id then I generarte random Id:

```
<% int randomId = new Random().Next(10000, 99999); %>
<textarea id="textarea-message-<%:randomId%>"></textarea>
<script>
$("#textarea-message-<%:randomId %>").textareaCount(...){...}
</script>
```

Can I have better solution for this situation?

Edit: I load usercontrols via ajax into page. so in the page there textareas binded and new textareas to bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my solution with class accessor and for multiple loading with ajax:

```
function doCountable(){
    var textareaToBind = $(".countable");
    $(textareaToBind).each(function(){
           $(this).removeClass("countable").addClass("countabled");
           $(this).textareaCount(...){...}
    })
}
```

I call doCountable() when page load and after ajax call

any correction or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class attribute to the textarea control and bind to that e.g.

```
<textarea class="countable" id="textarea-message-<%:randomId%>"></textarea>

<script>
$(".countable").textareaCount(...){...}
</script>
```

Dare I ask what the random thing is about?

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of id for all the `textarea` elements and bind that class with the textareaCount jQuery plugin function.